# Connecting to MySQL from Flask Application using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mysql-python

I have an application using Flask and MySQL. The application does not connect to MySQL container from the Flask Application but it can be accessed using Sequel Pro with the same credentials.

**Docker Compose File**

```
version: '2' 
services:
  web:
    build: flask-app
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
     - .:/code
  mysql:
    build: mysql-server
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: 0.0.0.0
      MYSQL_USER: testing
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: testing
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

**Docker file for MySQL**

The docker file for MySQL will add schema from `test.dump` file.

```
FROM mysql/mysql-server
ADD test.sql  /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

**Docker file for Flask**

```
FROM python:latest
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

**Starting point `app.py`**

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, Response
import json
import mysql.connector
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)

def getMysqlConnection():
    return mysql.connector.connect(user='testing', host='0.0.0.0', port='3306', password='testing', database='test')

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Flask inside Docker!!"

@app.route('/api/getMonths', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin() # allow all origins all methods.
def get_months():
    db = getMysqlConnection()
    print(db)
    try:
        sqlstr = "SELECT * from retail_table"
        print(sqlstr)
        cur = db.cursor()
        cur.execute(sqlstr)
        output_json = cur.fetchall()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error in SQL:\n", e)
    finally:
        db.close()
    return jsonify(results=output_json)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

When I do a GET request on `http://localhost:5000/` using REST Client I get a valid response.

A GET request on `http://localhost:5000/api/getMonths` gives error message:

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '0.0.0.0:3306' (111 Connection refused)
```

When the same credentials were used on Sequel Pro, I was able to access the database.
[image]

Please advice me on  how to connect the MySQL container from the Flask Application. This is my first time suing Docker and do forgive me if this is a silly mistake from my part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change this

```
return mysql.connector.connect(user='testing', host='0.0.0.0', port='3306', password='testing', database='test')
```

to

```
return mysql.connector.connect(user='testing', host='mysql', port='3306', password='testing', database='test')
```

Your code is running inside the container and not on your host. So you need to provide it a address where it can reach within container network. For `docker-compose` each service is reachable using its name. So in your it is `mysql` as that is name you have used for the service

Answer (score 1):

For others who encounter similar issue, if you are mapping different ports from host to container for the MySQL service, make sure that container that needs to connect to the MySQL service is using the port for the container not for the host.

Here is an example of a docker compose file. Here you can see that my application (which is running in a container) will be using port 3306 to connect to the MySQL service (which is also running in a container on port 3306). Anyone connecting to this MySQL service from the outside of the "backend" network which is basically anything that does not run in a container with the same network will need to use port 3308 to connect to this MySQL service.

```yaml
version: "3"
services:

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    command: redis-server --requirepass imroot
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - frontend

  mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.5
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql/data
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: imroot
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test_junkie_hq
      MYSQL_HOST: 127.0.0.1

  test-junkie-hq:
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - redis
    image: test-junkie-hq:latest
    ports:
      - "80:5000"
    networks:
      - backend
      - frontend
    environment:
      TJ_MYSQL_PASSWORD: imroot
      TJ_MYSQL_HOST: mysql
      TJ_MYSQL_DATABASE: test_junkie_hq
      TJ_MYSQL_PORT: 3306
      TJ_APPLICATION_PORT: 5000
      TJ_APPLICATION_HOST: 0.0.0.0

networks:
  backend:
  frontend:

volumes:
  mysql-data:
```