# Can't connect to MySQL server on db. nodename nor server provided or not known using Docker

Tags: flask

I'm trying to connect my application to my mysql database which I've got up and running in a docker-compose file. I'm using flask and trying to connect using DBUtils
I keep getting the error message described in my title:

(pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known)"))

I've tried using the IPAddresses of my docker instances as well as several other solutions in similar problems discussed here on StackOverflow:
[Docker-Compose can't connect to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58398715/docker-compose-cant-connect-to-mysql)
[Connecting to MySQL from Flask Application using docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658144/connecting-to-mysql-from-flask-application-using-docker-compose/45658385#45658385).

however, the offered solutions don't seem to be working for me.

my docker-compose file looks as follows:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'myPassword'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'databaseName'

    volumes:
      - .:/dockerFiles

    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose:
      - "3306"

phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin

    restart: always

    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - /sessions
```

and my connect string looks as follows:

```
def connect_db():
# Connects to the database and takes care of the connection
return PersistentDB(
    creator=pymysql, host='db',
    user='root', password='myPassword', database='databaseName', port=3306,
    autocommit=True, charset='utf8mb4',
    cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error `[Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known` states that it can't find the database server. Thus, `host='db'` will only work if your Python code is inside a docker in the same network of the database service `db`. Try adding a service for the Python code in your docker-compose:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'myPassword'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'databaseName'
    volumes:
      - .:/dockerFiles
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose:
      - "3306"

  web:
    build: . # where is your dockerfile
    command: sh -c 'python app.py' # this should be the command to start your application
    ports:
     - "8082:8082"
    volumes:
     - .:/code # it depends on the WORKDIR of your dockerfile
    links:
     - db
```

Comment: <apologies for all the edits, I did not realize that hitting 'enter' automatically posts rather than jumping to a new line>
Adding this to my docker-compose, I realized I needed to build a Dockerfile, so I went ahead and did so.
However, When I docker-compose up my new file, I do not see how I can now run my app from within Docker. When I do PS, I get the following:
``` 
mysql        docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up      0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
phpmyadmin   /docker-entrypoint.sh apac ...   Up      0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   
```

There is no sign of my new web service @Andre

Comment: To run your program from within docker, you need to create a command in the `web` service in you docker-compose.yml. I edited the answer with a more correct command `sh -c 'python app.py'`. The command itself depends on your side. For example, if you are using Flask, you may change the command to `sh -c 'flask run`'. The `sh -c` means that docker will use `sh` to run your program's starting command inside the docker. Then, you can access it in the browser through the ports you exposed, in the case, port `8082`. Just go to `http://127.0.0.1:8082` and check if it worked.